# Index not found (Stripe payment, Jquery, PHP) [Ghetto Fix = Read Edit Notes]

Tags: php, jquery

I'm following a tutorial step by step and I'm getting an undefined index error.

I tried this on my receive page: (submit.php)

```
if(isset($_POST['stripe-token'])){
var_dump($_POST['stripe-token']);}
else{ 
   echo "null"; 
}
```

but it comes back null.  This is how I am sending the 'stripe-token'

```
<script>

   Stripe.SetPublishableKey('my-key');

   $('#payment-form').submit(function(e){
   $form = $(this);
   //$form.find("button").prop('disabled', true);

   Stripe.card.createToken($form, function(status, response){
   var token = response.id;
    $form.append($('<input type="hidden" name="stripe-token"/>').val(token));
    $form.get(0).submit();
  });

  return false;

});

</script>
```

Payment form:

```
<form action="submit.php" class="form-horizontal" role="form" method="POST" id="payment-form">
```

Submit Button:

```
<button type="Submit" class="btn btn-success">Pay Now</button>
```

People say that Stripe is the easiest to set up, where are these people?

Comment: EDIT: I just ended up embedding the PHP on my form page and the token was successfully. If anyone know's how to make the 'stripe-token' POST to a new page, i'd still like to know

Answer (score 0):

I think set your JS like this.

```
 $form.append($('<input type="hidden" name="stripe-token"/>').val(token));
```

to

```
 $form.append('<input type="hidden" id="stripeToken" name="stripe-token"/>');
$("#stripeToken").val(token);
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but that didn't solve the issue either. :/